# method like 'dict.get' of python in Spark

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm a new Spark user and I code in Python. I create a pair RDD and then collect and broadcast it. Is there any method like `dict.get()` in python that I can use to get the value of the Broadcast object via keys, and set a default value when the key doesn't exist.
I got the report `AttributeError: 'Broadcast' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: What should be the input and output of that method?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Inputs are the key that you wish to access the value of, and a default value if the key doesn't exist. Output is the value of the key and when the key doesn't exist, return the default value.

Comment: @eliasah `value = dict.get(key, default=0)` I can get the value of the key in the dictionary through this line and if the key doesn't exist, return 0 to `value`.

Comment: I have updated my answer ! @orangedietc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broadcast variable is a wrapper around the value to broadcast, and its value can be accessed by calling the `value` method. The code below shows this:

```
>>> broadcastVar = sc.broadcast([1, 2, 3])
<pyspark.broadcast.Broadcast object at 0x102789f10>

>>> broadcastVar.value
[1, 2, 3]

>>> broadcastVar.value[1]
2
```

In our case, we have broadcasted a list but you might as well broadcast a dictionary :

```
>>> dict = {"a":1}
>>> sc.broadcast(dict).value
{'a': 1}
```

As stated earlier, the value method will return the underlying object and in this case, it's a dictionary so you just need to access it as such. So here is what you are looking for :

```
>>> print(sc.broadcast(dict).value.get("b", None))
None
>>> print(sc.broadcast(dict).value.get("a", None))
1
```

I have return `None` here but you might as well return anything you want :

```
>>> print(sc.broadcast(dict).value.get("v", -1))
-1
```

Check the official documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).

Comment: Thanks. But what I mean is, how can I access the value of the pair RDD which has been transformed into a broadcast object.

Comment: I don't get your question. You can't broadcast an RDD. You have to collect it and once collected you access it like a list

Comment: Yes I broadcast it after I collect it. I thought pair RDD is like dictionary. So what I wish to do is to access the value of it via the key, and also, set a default value which will be returned when the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! I get it. But I confront another problem. I collected and broadcast a pair RDD(represented by a 2-element tuple). But when we used `.value.get()`, I got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`.

Comment: That's because you are broadcasting a list. Read my answer again please !

Comment: I've read it. I said that I thought pair RDD is like dictionary. I broadcast a collected pair RDD.

Comment: A collected pair RDD is a list of tuples

Comment: Thanks for ur patience.